# Image becomes transparent on downscaling with ffmpeg

Tags: image-processing, ffmpeg

This is the original image of 200x200

[image]

On downscaling the image to 100x100. There is a semi transparent shadow near the lines and some pixels are not completely opaque.

[image]

The command used for scaling:
`ffmpeg -i test.png -vf scale=100x100 out.png`

I have also tried scaling with this command:
`ffmpeg -i test.png -vf scale=100x100 -sws_flags neighbor out.png`

The shadows are gone but the top line has also vanished.

[image]

How do I fix this ?

Comment: The shadows are probably a bug in the software you're using, but the rest is a natural consequence of resizing.  Nearest neighbor resizing will result in aliasing where features may be dropped.  Other algorithms will result in some blurring of features, including the transparency.

Comment: @MarkRansom Do you mean a bug in ffmpeg ?

Comment: Yes I do.  Ffmpeg is a great piece of software, used by millions around the world.  But it wasn't designed for still images with transparency, so it wouldn't surprise me that a subtle bug could go undetected.  You might try a different program such as ImageMagick or inside your own software.